# Finding vertices in a Vertex Group using Blender's Python API

Tags: python, mesh, scripting, vertices, vertex-groups

Is there an easy way to get the vertices in a vertex group?  The only way I've found is pretty brute-force - e.g., to find the vertices of object `obs[i]` in group "e":

```
e_idx = obs[i].vertex_groups['e'].index
vs=[v for v in obs[i].data.vertices if (v.groups)]
for v in vs:
    for g in v.groups:
        if (g.group == e_idx):
            es[i].append(v)
            break
```

Isn't there an easier way?  *I just found almost identical code in the ["Similar Questions"](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8075/checking-if-a-vertex-belongs-to-a-vertex-group-in-python/8085), so maybe this is the best there is.*

Answer (score 33, accepted):

## Methods

#### 1. List comprehension

As mentioned by Pycoder in the comments below, using operators is often slow. So a quicker and simpler (and X2 faster) method to get all the verts that belong to a certain vertex group index:

```
vg_idx = 0
o = bpy.context.object
vs = [ v for v in o.data.vertices if vg_idx in [ vg.group for vg in v.groups ] ]
```

#### 2. bpy.ops

You can also use the `bpy.ops.object.vertex_group_select` operator in edit mode:

```
import bpy

o = bpy.context.object

bpy.ops.object.mode_set( mode = 'EDIT' )

# Set the first vertex group as active:
o.vertex_groups.active = o.vertex_groups[0]

# Deselect all verts and select only current VG    
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all( action = 'DESELECT' )
bpy.ops.object.vertex_group_select()

# Now the selected vertices are the ones that belong to this VG
vgVerts = [ v for v in o.data.vertices if v.select ]
```

#### 3. Optimization if only one group

If there is only one group, this is a more optimized way to get the verts that belong to it. Note that this ***only*** works if there is only one vertex group.

```
vertices = [v for v in obj.data.vertices if v.groups]
```

## Performance testing

#### 1. List comprehension

With the default cube (8 vertices), this was timed 1,000,000 times, and had a [minimum value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220801/how-to-use-timeit-module#comment12782516_8220943) of:

> 0.000003528 seconds

With the default cube subdivided 8 times (393,218 vertices), this was timed 1,000 times, and had a [minimum value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220801/how-to-use-timeit-module#comment12782516_8220943) of:

> 0.1528 seconds

#### 2. bpy.ops

With the default cube (8 vertices), this was timed 10,000 times, and had a [minimum value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220801/how-to-use-timeit-module#comment12782516_8220943) of:

> 0.0003289 seconds

With the default cube subdivided 8 times (393,218 vertices), this was timed 100 times, and had a [minimum value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220801/how-to-use-timeit-module#comment12782516_8220943) of:

> 0.8849 seconds

#### 3. Optimization if only one group

With the default cube (8 vertices), this was timed 1,000,000 times, and had a [minimum value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220801/how-to-use-timeit-module#comment12782516_8220943) of:

> 0.00000222 seconds

With the default cube subdivided 8 times (393,218 vertices), this was timed 1,000 times, and had a [minimum value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220801/how-to-use-timeit-module#comment12782516_8220943) of:

> 0.0659 seconds

Here is a graphical (but less accurate) model if the performance. Each point is the [min](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220801/how-to-use-timeit-module#comment12782516_8220943) of 100 iterations.

[image]

Another representation of it:

[image]

Because the higher subdivision values make the lower end almost meaningless, we can use a logarithmic scale to see everything a bit more clearly:

[image]

## Additional links

https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?304054-Getting-vertices-of-a-vertex-group-from-within-Python

[Checking if a vertex belongs to a vertex group in python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8075/checking-if-a-vertex-belongs-to-a-vertex-group-in-python/8085)

[How can i get the weight for all vertices in a vertex group?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/46834/28015)

[vertex groups and bone weights programmatically](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/24170/28015)

[How can I get the names of the vertex groups these vertices are in?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/28235/28015)

Comment: `bpy.ops` are relatively slow; the scene is updated every time. This solution is not optimal, although it does work.

Comment: @pycoder yeah that's true. However he did ask for a simple solution, and I'm not all sure ops are slower than low level iterations if you have a really high poly mesh.

Comment: They are likely still slower, but not as much. This could be tested quite easily, though.

Comment: Would be interesting to test it. Many ops are written in cpp AFAIK, might give them an edge at least for large iterations.

Comment: @pycoder, tested with several subdivisions, seems like you were right and ops are always slower (by about twofold) - in this case

Comment: Beautiful list comprehension example...I was going to post the same thing, but you beat me to it, so I added the optimized technique to your answer rather than make another answer.

Comment: @pycoder that's some amazing stuff you've added to the answer. I'd feel a bit like a cheat for anyone who will (undoubtedly) upvote this answer because of all those great additions and viz. Got to go rest ahead of work related travel so can't join the chat at the moment, so just wanted to say thanks!

Comment: I was just asking if you wanted to make it a community wiki...the comments were getting lengthy, so I made the chat...

Comment: Great idea, done.

Comment: This is slightly different question, but relatable. Is there a batch method for assigning vertex weights fast? Looping through each vertex and doing ```add([i], value, "REPLACE")``` is extremely slow..

Comment: @VSB you should ask this as a new question, if I had to guess I might try to use vertex groups for that, especially if you want to assign identical weight to all members, but you'll likely get plenty of cool solutions.

Comment: I finally used this as an excuse to understand list comprehension. Very nice