# How can i remove verts in specific Group in VertexGroups via python?

Tags: python, objects, vertex-weights

i use Blender v2.76 and i try to remove vertices in specific Vertex Group via python ?

[image: Selected Group]

my specific group is atm "Test123" (only example), i try now via python to remove the selected vertices from the Group without index selection. is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

**Find verts in group, then remove.**

Methods to find vertices in vertex groups.

[Finding vertices in a Vertex Group using Blender's Python API](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75223/finding-vertices-in-a-vertex-group-using-blenders-python-api)

Once you have the verts in a group can remove them from their vertex group with

```
obj.vertex_groups["Group"].remove(index)
```

where index is the vertex index.